# I am struggiling in test mail?

Tags: android, string, android-studio

```
private void sendTestEmail() {
          String ename = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String desc=editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        String from=editTextFrom.getText().toString().trim();
        String to=editTextTo.getText().toString().trim();
        String genre = spinnerGenre.getSelectedItem().toString();
        BackgroundMail.newBuilder(this)
                .withUsername("xxx@gmail.com")
                .withPassword("yyy@123")
                .withMailto("zzz@gmail.com")
                .withSubject(ename)
                .withBody("from")
                .withOnSuccessCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnSuccessCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //do some magic
                    }
                })
                .withOnFailCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnFailCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFail() {
                        //do some magic
                    }
                })
                .send();
    }
```

but i got the error

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: net.rrcoding.firebasedatabaseexample, PID: 17529
                                                                                          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You didn't set a subject

Comment: does `ename` have a value there?

Comment: ename have a value..

Comment: then, the subject should have a value. i don't know why the error occurs.

Comment: I am also confused that..

Comment: try to check the value by using toast or log